# Styling input type=file not working as expected

Tags: css, forms

I'm creating a css template for form types and want to give form inputs a rounded border. This works well with type=text but doesn't work with type=file (for file upload).

What am I doing wrong?

```
.tempform input[type="text"] {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

.tempform input[type="file"] {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

<div class="tempform">
   <label for="textfield">Test Text Field</label>
   <input type="text" id="textfield" name="textfield"></div>
</div>

div class="tempform">
   <label for="filefield">Test File Field</label>
   <input type="file" name="filefield" id="filefield-0">
   <input type="file" name="filefield" id="filefield-1">
</div>
```

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=style+input+file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to style a file upload input, besides changing the width a little bit. Browsers just don't allow any other change. If you want to style your file upload input, you'll have to use a nasty hack like placing an almost invisible file upload input on top of an image (which only works in some browsers), or a JavaScript solution like [ajax-upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Answer (score 2):

According to [the first Google search result](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+style+file+input), it's rather involved. See [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) on quirksmode.org for information on how to do it.