# styling height of an input type file button

Tags: css

I'm trying to style an input type file with an image. so far, so good, but now I want to set the height of that button on 40px. The problem is that, somehow, this button has a fixed height and even when i put !important next to the 40px of the size, the button still shows the original height. can somebody help me with this? thank you
here it is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <LINK href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
<input type="text" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly">

<div class="file_input_div">
  <input type="button" value="" class="file_input_button" />
  <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value" /> 
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.file_input_textbox
{
    float: left;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF554B;
    border: medium none;
    color: #FFFEFA;
    font-family: 'InterstateBold';
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    width: 647px;
}

.file_input_div
{
    position: relative; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 23px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.file_input_button
{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    background:url(btn-newsletter.jpg) no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-style: none;
    width:40px;
    height:40px !important;
}

.file_input_button:hover
{

    background:url(btn-newsletter2.jpg) no-repeat !important;

}

.file_input_hidden
{
    font-size: 45px; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    opacity: 0; 

    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)"; 
    -khtml-opacity: 0; 
    -moz-opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: it might be easier to help you if you show us the css and html

Comment: You can share a sample of your code, using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling input type=file not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664220/styling-input-type-file-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: in fact, tons of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=style+input+file

Comment: Your first link of a duplication its nothing like this one. My button show the image, just don't change the height. But thank you.

Comment: This is probably not possible - hence the duplicate links are probably your best option, see there what can be done instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured i out. As an `input type="file"` and `input type="button"` don't let me change the height, i change this line: `<input type="button" value="" class="file_input_button" />`
to this: `<a href="#" class="file_input_button" />` and change the css to:

```
.file_input_div
{
    position: relative; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 38px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The correct css syntax however, no matter if it lets you style the height or not (I don't know).
Is:

```
input[type=file] {
    //your style rules
}
```